# How can compiler optimizations affect code logic?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, compiler-optimization

When the same piece of code is compiled with optimizations fully disabled (`g++ -O0`) and then again with the optimizations fully enabled (`g++ -O3`), how can the logic of the source code itself be changed?

For example, compilers can

- [unwind loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) and
- do [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding).

These two optimizations make the code perform faster without affecting the integrity of the original source code. Any code that runs without these optimizations will run with them enabled.

But, compiler optimizations can also affect code logic. Here are two examples that I know of:

- [Removing copy constructors and assignment operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) from temporaries may remove possible side-effects.
- Rearranging arithmetic containing floating point values may affect floating point error (hopefully requires `-ffast-math` argument).

I was very surprised, and lucky, to learn about these because they could become huge potential gotchas in the wrong situation.

So I want to know, are there any other cases where c++ compiler optimizations will affect code logic? I'm specifically looking for information about c++11 (without any undefined behaviour) under the g++ compiler, but tips for other compilers are welcome.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that undefined behavior will mean anything goes.

Comment: I believe the compiler can also 'not compute' stuff that is never used later. While this doesn't change the logic of your code, it might be bad if you're measuring performance. I'm not sure about this though.

Comment: @leo Good point! Although, I'd always expect compiling with optimizations will perform faster, because that's the optimizer's job.

Comment: I think put more succinctly, is your question: what are all the exceptions to the as-if rule?

Comment: @Mysticial Even more, undefined behaviour means anything goes, _even before the point in the program where the UB occurs_.

Comment: IMO any compiler optimization which changes 'code logic' from the way you wrote it is failing, and that's basically a compiler bug.

Comment: @Dave that's true only if "the way you wrote it" is well-defined by the C++ language.  It's not too difficult to write C++ code whose expected behavior is not defined by the language spec, and in that case the compiler is free to do just about anything it wants and blame you for any problems that occur ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "as-if" Rule:

> **An implementation is free to disregard any requirement of this
> International Standard as long as the result is as if the requirement
> had been obeyed**, as far as can be determined from the observable
> behavior of the program. For instance, an actual implementation need
> not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is
> not used and that no side effects affecting the observable behavior of
> the program are produced.

However, the standard mentions one optimization which is allowed, and which breaks the "as-if" rule:

> When certain criteria are met, **an implementation is allowed to omit
> the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the copy/move
> constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects.** In
> such cases, the implementation treats the source and target of the
> omitted copy/move operation as simply two different ways of referring
> to the same object, and the destruction of that object occurs at the
> later of the times when the two objects would have been destroyed
> without the optimization.123 This elision of copy/move operations,
> called copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances
> (which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies):
>
> — in a return
> statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression
> is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function
> or catch-clause parameter) with the same cvunqualified type as the
> function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
> constructing the automatic object directly into the function’s return
> value
>
> — in a throw-expression, when the operand is the name of a
> non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause
> parameter) whose scope does not extend beyond the end of the innermost
> enclosing try-block (if there is one), the copy/move operation from
> the operand to the exception object (15.1) can be omitted by
> constructing the automatic object directly into the exception object
>
> —
> when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference
> (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same
> cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
> constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the
> omitted copy/move
>
> — when the exception-declaration of an exception
> handler (Clause 15) declares an object of the same type (except for
> cv-qualification) as the exception object (15.1), the copy/move
> operation can be omitted by treating the exception-declaration as an
> alias for the exception object if the meaning of the program will be
> unchanged except for the execution of constructors and destructors for
> the object declared by the exception-declaration.

Answer (score 1):

"Unspecified Behavior" is behavior where the implementation is free to choose any of the possible behaviors. In such cases, an optimizer may affect the choice made.

A simple example is the order in which arguments to a function are evaluated. Non-optimized builds could use Left-to-Right or Right-to-Left, whereas optimized builds may evaluate arguments in a "mixed" order. A good reason would be to maximize the opportunity for Common Subexpression Optimization amongst arguments.

If any of these arguments has noticeable side effects, the code logic would be altered, but whether that's a bug varies from case to case.